# Does the Futurama TV show have jokes relating to the 1939 Futurama exhibit?

Tags: futurama

I’m curious about the relationship of the TV show Futurama and the original [Norman Bel Geddes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norman_Bel_Geddes) exhibit from which it took its name.  Are there any specific jokes or Easter eggs in the show relating to Bel Geddes and his life/philosophy?  Or is there anything in any episode scripts that overtly references the original 1939 Futurama?  The setting aesthetic is similar to the original, but I am more curious about jokes that are actually voiced or acted out.

Comment: What do you mean by "caveats"?

Comment: @user14111 Basically anything that shows that the artist or director wanted to specifically reference Bel Geddes or the original Futurama to the viewer - rather than just using it for aesthetic inspiration. This can be a foggy area in stuff like background design, which is why I'm thinking more in terms of dialogue or script.

Comment: OK. I thought "caveats" were "warnings".

Comment: Yes, the usual meaning of "caveat" is a warning or caution, often a condition you're telling people has to be kept in mind about a certain statement in order to avoid misunderstanding it or interpreting it too broadly.

Comment: Cameos! @$#&. I was thinking cameos. Serious brain fart right there. Although I think Easter eggs is even better.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is as overtly a reference as you’re going to get:

[image]

The title card for the episode “[The Inhuman Torch](https://theinfosphere.org/The_Inhuman_Torch)”.

Comment: Signed, sealed, delivered.

Answer (score 24):

The most noticeable one is right there in the first episode, immediately after Fry awakens in the year 3000. The cryogenic technician steps into the room and dramatically exclaims "Welcome to the World of Tomorrow!":

[image: Welcome to the World of Tomorrow]

This seems to have been taken almost verbatim from the theme of the 1939 World's Fair, described by Wikipedia as "The World of Tomorrow", and evident in promotional material for the fair:

[image: Unlock the World of Tomorrow]

Answer (score 3):

Also in one episode there was a "Past-o-Rama" exhibit- a sort of 'old world's fair' depicting a very inaccurate picture of old-New-York and twentieth century life (they thought Albert Einstein and Hammurabi were around during the days of Disco), this was probably meant as a parody of the 1939 futurama exhibit.